# When I delete multiple product in my basket only first products quantity return my DB other products quantity didn't return

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

When you add a product to the cart, the number of products in stock decreases and when you remove the product from the cart, it returns to the old stock number.

What I want to do the deletion automatically every half hour. This code only works for one product. When I add the second product to the cart, only the first product's stock is returned. Can you help me?

I tried mongoose expire but it just cleans the database and the stocks don't come back.

And when I add the second product I get this error:

```js
[
  {
    _id: 60b3487145fab827845f87b1,
    productId: 60b24b9e89389908c8bbb3b2,
    quantity: 1
  }
]
user.product:  60b24b9e89389908c8bbb3b2 productId:  60b24b9e89389908c8bbb3b2
[
  {
    _id: 60b3487145fab827845f87b1,
    productId: 60b24b9e89389908c8bbb3b2,
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    _id: 60b3487a45fab827845f87b2,
    productId: 60b25119c9f0da205409d6ce,
    quantity: 1
  }
]
user.product:  60b24b9e89389908c8bbb3b2 productId:60b25119c9f0da205409d6ce
user.product:  60b25119c9f0da205409d6ce productId:  60b25119c9f0da205409d6ce
```

this is my code:

```js
setTimeout(async function(){
            const items = await req.user.cart.items;
            console.log(items);
            for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
                var user = items[i];
                console.log("user.product: ", user.productId, "productId: ", productId);
                if(user.productId == productId){
                    var result = items[i].quantity;
                }
            }
            
            const product = await Product.findById(productId);
            const productQuantity = product.productQuantity;
            const productQuantityResult = productQuantity + Number(result);
            product.productQuantity = productQuantityResult;
            await req.user.deleteCartItem(productId);
            await product.save();
        },  20000);
```

Comment: `items` is the list of the product IDs which are added into the cart and you want to increment every product value? And can you explain `user.productId == productId` why are you doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can directly take the product id from the cart object and update the respective product count using the update query. Assuming cart schema that you shown in the question code.

First, we get the productID added in the cart and the quantity. There can be different ways of doing this, you can also use `aggregation pipeline` or `bulkwrite`, but I am trying to keep it simple.

```
setTimeout(async function(){
        try{
            const items = await req.user.cart.items;
            const queries = [];
            for(let i=0; i<items.length; i++){
               // you can add the condition here
               // though every cart product has to be removed so we will make 
               // multiple queries, validate the queries values correctness
               // as I am not sure about the schema, but this way will work
                const query = {'_id': items[i].productId, {{ $inc: { productQuantity: items[i].quantity }}};
                queries.push(query);
            }
            const product = await Product.insertMany(queries);
            // check the product status and continue deleting the cart values
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(`Error occurred: ${e}`);
          }
        },  20000);
```

Comment: You can add comment here.

Answer (score 0):

To compare the product id of the product we added to the cart with the product id in the cart and delete the matched one. @Apoorva Chikara